# calculate median for a given input data and its frequencies

Tags: algorithm, median

I am given the following input:

```
num: counts
1:5
2:4
3:8
```

This the number to frequency ratio:

In order to calculate the median of this input, I did a naive way which is filling up an array with these elements

```
>>>l = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
>>>i = len(l)/2
>>> median = l[i] if not i%2 else l[i+1]
>>> median
2
```

This is correct. However, I am unnecessarily using an array to fill up.
I am wondering if there is a mathematical way to get at median given number and its frequency of occurrence.

and

Comment: just an observation: you don't need the if-else statement, just do median = l[len(l)/2]

Comment: Will the values always be provided in order?  Is it possible to know the number of values before they're provided?  Are the values in a known limited range?

Comment: @MooingDuck: we can assume that the input data is sorted. Bu the range is not known

Answer (score 3):

You can start summing the frequencies in order, and you find the median when the sum goes over half of the total count.

```
counts = {1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 8}
total = sum(counts.values())
s = 0
for k in sorted(counts.keys()):
  s += counts[k]
  if s > total / 2:
    break
print 'median:', k
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need exact median or estimated median.

To get exact median you can iterate on the frequency set and keep adding frequency value. When the sum is greater than half of total return the element. Equivalent in ruby (assuming input is sorted by keys):

```
def median(h)
  half = h.values.inject(:+).to_f/2
  sort = h.sort 
  sum = 0
  prev = 0
  sort.each do |k, v|
    if prev.nonzero?
      return (k + prev).to_f/2
    end
    sum+=v
    if sum == half 
      prev = k
    elsif sum > half
      return k
    end
  end
end

median({1=>5, 2 => 4, 3 => 8})
```

There exists a formula to calculate estimated media

```
median = l + ((n/2) − cfb)*w/fm
```

where

- l is the lower class boundary of the group containing the median
- n is the total number of data
- cfb is the cumulative frequency of the groups before the median group
- fm is the frequency of the median group
- w is the group width

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is completely sorted, as the input you have provided is, you can do this:
sum the frequencies of each number. If even, divide by 2. If odd, add 1 to the frequency and divide by two. In the sample input you provided, doing this would yield 9.

Now sum the frequency of inputs and stop once they reach 9. The value (num) that is beside the frequency you stopped at is your median. In this case, it's 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of cumulative sums (e.g. cumsum() in pandas or numpy). Here's an example.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series([5,4,8], index = [1,2,3])


data.sort_index()                   # sort just in case
mid  = data.sum() / 2.0             # index of the middle element

cum = data.cumsum()                 # cumulative sums of your data frequencies
median = cum[cum >= mid].argmin()   # ignore the first half of the data and get the 
                                    # index of the median element
```